# Why Markdown rather than Markup?

Tags: support, markdown

A question that's been bugging me. Why does SO (and I assume the rest of SE) call the *code* formatting of posts **Markdown**? I would have thought **Markup** would make sense to most people. Is it the actual name of the language?

I'm not a regular on Internet bulletin boards, so I'm not aware if other similar sites use the same term.

Comment: Research effort? First result on Google is [Markdown's Wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown)

Comment: The Editing Help contains a link to Mark Gruber's web pages; his *philosophy* is that "[a] Markdown-formatted document should be publishable as-is, as plain text, without looking like it’s been marked up with tags or formatting instructions." Hence, it's quite the *opposite* of 'mark up'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[That is the name of the syntax.](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)

There is also a new one called [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/) which may or may not be adopted at some point.